# Closure doesn't work

Tags: ruby, closures

If a block is a closure, why does this code does not work, and how to make it work?

```
def R(arg)
  Class.new do
    def foo
      puts arg
    end
  end
end

class A < R("Hello!")
end

A.new.foo #throws undefined local variable or method `arg' for #<A:0x2840538>
```

Comment: Can we see your error messages?

Comment: Error message is under comment in the sample.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Blocks are closures and `arg` is indeed available inside the `Class.new` block. It's just not available inside the `foo` method because `def` starts a new scope. If you replace `def` with `define_method`, which takes a block, you'll see the result you want:

```
def R(arg)
    Class.new do
        define_method(:foo) do
           puts arg
        end
    end
end

class A < R("Hello!")
end

A.new.foo # Prints: Hello!
```

Comment: how would a method that takes parameters be defined?

Comment: @Geo: Using a block which takes parameters. E.g. `define_method(:add_one) do |x| x+1 end`

Answer (score 5):

If you define the class dynamically, you can alter it as you like:

```
def R(arg)
  c = Class.new

  # Send the block through as a closure, not as an inline method
  # definition which interprets variables always as local to the block.
  c.send(:define_method, :foo) do
    arg
  end

  c
end

class A < R("Hello!")
end

puts A.new.foo.inspect
# => "Hello!"
```